# MySQL very slow query

Tags: mysql, sql

My table has the following columns:

```
gamelogs_id (auto_increment primary key)
player_id (int)
player_name (varchar)
game_id (int)
season_id (int)
points (int)
```

The table has the following indexes

```
+-----------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table           | Non_unique | Key_name           | Seq_in_index | Column_name        | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| player_gamelogs |          0 | PRIMARY            |            1 | player_gamelogs_id | A         |      371330 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| player_gamelogs |          1 | player_name        |            1 | player_name        | A         |        3375 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| player_gamelogs |          1 | points          |            1 | points          | A         |         506 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         ## Heading ##|               |
| player_gamelogs |          1 | game_id            |            1 | game_id            | A         |       37133 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| player_gamelogs |          1 | season             |            1 | season             | A         |          30 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| player_gamelogs |          1 | team_abbreviation  |            1 | team_abbreviation  | A         |          70 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| player_gamelogs |          1 | player_id          |            1 | game_id            | A         |       41258 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| player_gamelogs |          1 | player_id          |            2 | player_id          | A         |      371330 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| player_gamelogs |          1 | player_id          |            3 | dk_points          | A         |      371330 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| player_gamelogs |          1 | game_player_season |            1 | game_id            | A         |       41258 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| player_gamelogs |          1 | game_player_season |            2 | player_id          | A         |      371330 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| player_gamelogs |          1 | game_player_season |            3 | season_id          | A         |      371330 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

I am trying to calculate the mean of points for a season and player prior to the game being played. So for the 3rd game of the season, avg_points would be the mean of games 1 and 2. The game numbers are in sequential order such that an earlier game is less than a later game. I also have the option to use a date field but I figured that numeric comparison would be faster?

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT game_id, 
       player_id, 
       player_name, 
       (SELECT avg(points) 
          FROM player_gamelogs t2
         WHERE t2.game_id < t1.game_id 
           AND t1.player_id = t2.player_id 
           AND t1.season_id = t2.season_id) AS avg_points
  FROM player_gamelogs t1
 ORDER BY player_name, game_id;
```

EXPLAIN produces the following output:

```
| id | select_type        | table | type | possible_keys                        | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                           |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | t1    | ALL  | NULL                                 | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 371330 | Using filesort                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | t2    | ALL  | game_id,player_id,game_player_season | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 371330 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0xC8) |
```

I am not sure if it is because of the nature of the task involved or because of an inefficiency in my query. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: How many rows is there on player_gamelogs ? And have you tried to execute an explain plan of your query?

Comment: Just a thought, why are you selecting the avg_points, in the same select with a subselect to that named field. Maybe you are running some sort of recursive problem. Try to remove that column `avg_points` And see what happens. Not sure though.

Comment: ~250,000 rows. The avg_points was an error in posting the question to Stack Overflow - it is not in the actual query.

Comment: Can you also explain on your question what data you are trying to fetch? Don't seems logic to me this operation `t2.game_id < t1.game_id`

Comment: is `game_id` unique?

Comment: game_id is unique per group (which is a single player) but not in the table as a whole because multiple players are in the same game

Comment: OK - I actually realized it does not matter. Please try my query below.

Comment: t2.game_id < t1.game_id limits the games to those prior to the current game

Comment: Can a player have in a same game and same season two or more registered points (more than one row)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please consider this query:

```
SELECT t1.season_id, t1.game_id, t1.player_id, t1.player_name, AVG(COALESCE(t2.points, 0)) AS average_player_points
FROM player_gamelogs t1
        LEFT JOIN player_gamelogs t2 ON 
                t1.game_id > t2.game_id 
            AND t1.player_id = t2.player_id
            AND t1.season_id = t2.season_id 
GROUP BY
    t1.season_id, t1.game_id, t1.player_id, t1.player_name
ORDER BY t1.player_name, t1.game_id;
```

Notes:

- To perform optimally, you'd need an additional index on (season_id, game_id, player_id, player_name)
- Even better, would be to have player table where to retrieve the name from the id. It seems redundant to me that we have to grab the player name from a log table, moreover if it's required in an index.
- `Group by` already sorts by grouped columns. If you can, avoid ordering afterwards as it generates useless overhead. *As outlined in the comments, this is not an official behavior and the outcome of assuming its consistency over time should be pondered vs the risk of suddenly losing sorting.*

Comment: How did it turn out?

Comment: "Group by already sorts by grouped columns" is a risky assumption that could produce bugs. The only clause guaranteed to provide sorting of the result is ORDER BY.

Comment: @Used_By_Already that is correct. I felt like this still was a valuable feedback as it does impact performance.

Comment: I'm fine with it as long as the person knows there is a risk (so I mentioned it :)

Comment: Thank you. I should have mentioned it myself as it IS sort of a side effect, not an official behaviour. Let me update my answer

Answer (score 2):

Your query is fine as written:

```
SELECT game_id, player_id, player_name, 
       (SELECT avg(t2.points) 
        FROM player_gamelogs t2
        WHERE t2.game_id < t1.game_id AND
              t1.player_id = t2.player_id AND
              t1.season_id = t2.season_id
      ) AS avg_points
FROM player_gamelogs t1
ORDER BY player_name, game_id;
```

But, for optimal performance you want two composite indexes on it: `(player_id, season_id, game_id, points)` and `(player_name, game_id, season_id)`.

The first index should speed the subquery.  The second is for the outer `order by`.

Comment: Despite the general "covering index" theory, I was wondering whether the points would make sense for this query. I'd try without it first I guess...

Comment: @Sebas . . . `points` clearly is not as important as `player_id` and `season_id`.  But a covering index allows the engine to avoid uses the data pages, which saves on I/O.

Answer (score 1):

As you have your query now, you are running for EACH game and all the games under it for every player...  So, for example, if you had 10 games per person, you are getting the following results per season/person

```
Game 10, Game 10 points, avg of games 1-9
Game 9, Game 9 points, avg of games 1-8...
...
...
Game 2, Game 2 points, avg of thus final game 1 only.
```

You stated you wanted the most recent game with the average of everything under it.  That said, I am assuming you do NOT care about each of the lower game levels per person.

You are also doing the query covering ALL seasons.  If a season is finished, do you care about old seasons? or just the current season.  Otherwise you are going through all seasons, all players...

All that said, I offer the following. First, limit the query to whatever the latest season is by using the WHERE clause, but I am INTENTIONALLY leaving the season in the query / group by in case you DO want other seasons.  Then, I am getting the MAXIMUM game for a given person / season as the baseline for the final 1 row (per person season), then getting the average of everything under that.  So, in the scenario sample of 10 games down to 2, I won't be grabbing the underlying rows 9-2, just returning the #10 game per my scenario.

```
select
      pgMax.Player_ID,
      pgMax.Season_ID,
      pgMax.mostRecentGameID,
      pgl3.points as mostRecentGamePoints,
      pgl3.player_name,
      coalesce( avg( pgl2.points ), 0 ) as AvgPointsPriorToCurrentGame
   from
      ( select pgl1.player_id,
               pgl1.season_id,
               max( pgl1.game_id ) as mostRecentGameID
           from
              player_gameLogs pgl1
           where
               pgl1.season_id = JustOneSeason
           group by
              pgl1.player_id,
              pgl1.season_id ) pgMax

         JOIN player_gamelogs pgl pgl2
            on pgMax.player_id = pgl2.player_id
           AND pgMax.season_id = pgl2.season_id
           AND pgMax.mostRecentGameID > pgl2.game_id

         JOIN player_gamelogs pgl pgl3
            on pgMax.player_id = pgl3.player_id
           AND pgMax.season_id = pgl3.season_id
           AND pgMax.mostRecentGameID = pgl3.game_id
   group by
      pgMax.Player_ID,
      pgMax.Season_ID
   order by
      pgMax.Player_ID
```

Now, for optimizing the query, a composite index would be best on
(player_id, season_id, game_id, points).  HOWEVER, if you are only looking for whatever "the current season" is, then have your index on (season_id, player_id, game_id, points) putting the SEASON ID in first position to prequalify the WHERE clause.